# Dynamic Conditional String

Tags: php, eval

I have the code below taken partially inside a function:

```
$dynamic_comparison = '';  
if(($from == '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 1;
}else if(($from != '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = '($row >= $from) && ($row <= $to)';
}else if(($from != '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = '($row >= $from)';
}else if(($from == '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = '($row <= $to)';
}
```

`$form`, `$to` and `$row` are the parameters of the function.

I want to evaluate `$dynamic_comparison` into something like this:

```
if($dynamic_comparison){
    //A bunch of code here...
}
```

I tried:

```
if(eval($dynamic_comparison)){
    //A bunch of code here...
}
```

It throws an error. How to get this right?

Answer (score 1):

eval() is bad idea imho.
You can use anonymous function, like this

```
$dynamic_comparison = function($row, $to, $from) { return false };  
if(($from == '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = function($row, $to, $from) { return true;};
}else if(($from != '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = function($row, $to, $from) { return ($row >= $from) && ($row <= $to);};
}else if(($from != '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = function($row, $to, $from) { return ($row >= $from);};
}else if(($from == '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = function($row, $to, $from) { return ($row <= $to);};
}
```

And use it like

```
if($dynamic_comparison($row, $to, $from))...
```

If you want to use eval anyway:

```
$dynamic_comparison = 'return false;';  
if(($from == '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 'return true;';
}else if(($from != '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 'return ($row >= $from) && ($row <= $to);';
}else if(($from != '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 'return ($row >= $from);';
}else if(($from == '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 'return ($row <= $to);';
}

if(eval($dynamic_comparison)){//$to,$from,$row must be available in this scope
```

Comment: I want to know, why is it a bad idea? :)

Comment: Because usage may have unexpected side effects

Comment: @Aliyah ok, if you want use eval, you must write string like ``'return ($row >= $from) && ($row <= $to);'`` or ``'return 1;'`` - this will work with eval

Comment: I still dont get it :(

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use double quotes insted of single quotes for your string like this :

```
<?php 
$dynamic_comparison = '';  
if(($from == '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = 1;
}else if(($from != '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = "($row >= $from) && ($row <= $to)";
}else if(($from != '')&&($to == '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = "($row >= $from)";
}else if(($from == '')&&($to != '')){
    $dynamic_comparison = "($row <= $to)";
}
```

if you don't have $row initialezed at this moment , escape $ character :

```
<?php 
    $dynamic_comparison = '';  
    if(($from == '')&&($to == '')){
        $dynamic_comparison = 1;
    }else if(($from != '')&&($to != '')){
        $dynamic_comparison = "(\$row >= $from) && (\$row <= $to)";
    }else if(($from != '')&&($to == '')){
        $dynamic_comparison = "(\$row >= $from)";
    }else if(($from == '')&&($to != '')){
        $dynamic_comparison = "(\$row <= $to)";
    }
```

see eval() documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php